# gerrit command "ls-members" gives me an error: fatal: "-" is not a valid option

Tags: gerrit

In my test gerrit, I have below groups;

```
ssh -p 29418 user@example.com gerrit ls-groups --project prj1/mysampleprj
Administrators
Applications - Maintainers
Applications - Reviewers
```

`ls-members "Administors"` are fine.

But `ls-members "Applications - Maintainers"` gives me an error like;

```
fatal: "-" is not a valid option
```

Can you please guide me how to get list of "Applications - Maintainers" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the usual suspect `\` for escaping.

The correct command/query would be:

```
ssh -p 29418 user@example.com gerrit ls-members "Applications\ -\ Maintainers"
```